# is there a term for when you use two words with a slash in between to label something?

Tags: nouns

If I used the label religiosity/spirituality, would it be called a compound label or something like that?

Comment: I think it's called "indecision".

Comment: If it's specifically "as a label", then probably not. If you just want a term for "joining two words with a slash" then one might exist...

Comment: I call it an _either/or_, in honor of the great [Søren Kierkegaard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Either/Or).

Comment: If there were a way of deducing whether the slash meant 'and' or 'or' or 'and/or' then it might be worth considering. As it is, see Hot Licks…